# cytoscape.js & meteor simple example doesnt work

Tags: javascript, meteor, cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

1. i added to meteor cytoscape : infinitedg:cytoscape
2. i have very basic meteor app:

hello.js   http://pastebin.com/2frsHc9g
hello.html  http://pastebin.com/10EYyJ74

but i am not able to make it work

here is error i can see in console of web browser:

> on rendered zavolana hello.js:9 ss [object Object] debug.js:41
>   Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: debug.js:41 TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
>       at CanvasRenderer.registerBinding (infinitedg_cytoscape.js:17127)
>       at CanvasRenderer.load (infinitedg_cytoscape.js:17283)
>       at new CanvasRenderer (infinitedg_cytoscape.js:13419)
>       at $$.fn.core.initRenderer (infinitedg_cytoscape.js:7527)
>       at new $$.Core (infinitedg_cytoscape.js:6592)
>       at Function.$$.init (infinitedg_cytoscape.js:75)
>       at cytoscape (infinitedg_cytoscape.js:58)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (infinitedg_cytoscape.js:2808)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.each (jquery.js:384)
>       at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (jquery.js:136)

do you have please some "hello world"  of combination of cytoscape and meteor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem was with wrong library installed via meteor

after i installed correct cytoscape library, it is working

correct is cytoscape:cytoscape

here is minimal and working [example](https://github.com/mraky/meteorcytoscape_minimal):

**JS**

```js
sit = "" //hlavni objekt

if (Meteor.isClient) {




    Template.graf.rendered = function() {

        // Meteor.defer(function() {
        //setTimeout(function(){

        console.log("on rendered called");
        //var divcy = $('#cy');
        // console.log("ss " + divcy);
        sit = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById('cy'),


            ready: function() {
                console.log("network ready");
                updateNetworkData(sit); // load data when cy is ready
            },

            style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
                .selector('node')
                .style({
                    'content': function(e) {
                        return e.data("name")
                    },

                    'font-size': 12,
                    'text-valign': 'center',
                    'color': 'white',
                    'text-outline-width': 2,
                    'text-outline-color': function(e) {
                        return e.locked() ? "red" : "#888"
                    },
                    'min-zoomed-font-size': 8
                        // 'width': 'mapData(score, 0, 1, 20, 50)',
                        // 'height': 'mapData(score, 0, 1, 20, 50)'
                })
                .selector('edge')
                .style({
                    'content': function(e) {
                        return e.data("name") ? e.data("name") : "";
                    },
                    'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                })


        });

        //})
    }




}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        // code to run on server at startup
    });
}



function updateNetworkData(net) {

    // init Data

    var nodes = [{ // node a
            group: 'nodes',
            data: {
                id: 'a',
                name:'a'
            }
        }, { // node b
            group: 'nodes',
            data: {
                id: 'b',
              name:'b'
            }
        }

    ]
    var edges = [{ // edge ab
            group: 'edges',
            data: {
                id: 'ab',
              name:'ab',
                source: 'a',
                target: 'b'
            }
        }

    ]

    net.elements().remove(); // make sure evything is clean

    net.add(nodes);
    net.add(edges);

    net.reset() // render layout
}
```

**CSS**

```css
#cy {
  width : 70vw;
  height: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!b</h1>
  {{>graf}}
</body>

<template name="graf">
  <div id="cy"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: 1 correction - originaly i wrote "correct is maxkfranz:cytoscape" ,  but maxkfranz edited it to "correct is cytoscape:cytoscape"   . unfortunately this example is not working with  "cytoscape:cytoscape", but works with maxkfranz:cytoscape .. i am checkking why, and will update answer to fit  it .. I guess maxkfranz want to use for future  cytoscape:cytoscape

Comment: i gaveup trying  to make meteor package cytoscape:cytoscape.js working...   i am not experienced in javascript enough to find reason. what i see i can make cytoscape:cytoscape.js working only with layout "circle"... i failed to make cose working... also i could not add any other ( like cose-bilkent )   in short this example is working only with  maxkfranz:cytoscape ,and i am trying to put toghter some better description to cytoscape.js issue tracker about this...

Comment: I have also found that cytoscape:cytoscape does not work on Meteor. maxkfranz:cytoscape does, but I am finding it difficult to implement alot of functionality for that too. It seems alot easier to just build a web page from scratch.

Comment: @thegreenfrog  - actuallly i am moving ahead... i thing in week or 2 i will update both my questions here on stacks...